# .NET 7 cannot access MySQL database but only if app is published

Tags: c#, .net, rider

Why does a C# .NET 7 console application, when executed from Rider IDE (on Mac M1, or Windows Server 2019, or, on any environment), run without problems, but, when published to Windows, it cannot access MySQL (5.7 or Aurora) database because of "The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception"?

Comment: can you provide the full stack trace message ?

Comment: How did you publish it? On IIS or not?

Comment: Note that MySQL is a separate application; it is not part of your application and if you want to use it you have to install it separately. If you publish your app to another machine you must ensure MySQL is also installed on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that on your Exception there is an error related to the ConfigurationManager I can say that it is not part of .NET Core
Use [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) instead of MySqlData, the first has not dependency on compatibility packages in .NET Core